# How do you run a Java Web Start program at startup/logon using launchd on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

It took me a while to figure out and I haven't seen any other references online regarding this.

Answer (score 4):

Use vi to create a file at a path like this:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myprogram.plist
```

The file should contain this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
           http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.docuvantage.dvdesktop</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/javaws</string>
            <string>-Xnosplash</string>
            <string>http://www.mycompany.com/pub/myprogram.jnlp</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Verify the file syntax like this:

```
plutil -lint ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myprogram.plist
```

Test the configuration:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myprogram.plist
```

Unload so you can test again:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mycompany.myprogram.plist
```

You must set AbandonProcessGroup to true to keep launchd from killing your application. The javaws executable forks a couple times and creates sub-processes and then javaws quits. By default launchd then sees that the program quit and kills all the sub-processes that it spawned.

Do not bother trying to use the `-wait` switch for javaws. It does not work.

Because `-wait` does not work you cannot use the `KeepAlive` setting.